# Alert and Newsfeed notifications stopped working

Tags: 2013, mysites, exchange, notifications

We are having a major issue with notifications in our Production environment. Users are not receiving alerts when they subscribe to any doc library. Notifications in Mysites are not being set out either. We tried rebuilding the UPS application but that didn't fix the problem.

This was all working up until a couple weeks ago and also works in our 2 other Dev environments. I can also send emails using custom code without issues. It makes me think it has something to do with our Office 365 / Exchange setup but our infrastructure team doesn't want to cooperate so we need to narrow it down a little more. We have SharePoint 2013 on-prem with Office 365 for email. Any ideas on where to start with this? I've read something about adding another MX record..

Comment: In office 365 exchange try message trace. Also check quarantine and make sure email are not getting quarantined.

Comment: Alright, would I do this from an admin account or from the account expecting the notification?

Comment: You should login as Office 365 Admin, then click on Exchange. Then you can see these menu items on left navigation.

Comment: I'm getting our Exchange admin to look into this. I'll check back and accept your answer if it works. ty Amal

Comment: sure, let me know if it fixes then I will post it as an answer.

Comment: nothing in either of those, @AmalHashim. We get the initial notification when setting the alert or loading mysite for the first time. But no further emails come through. Nothing when editing / deleting a document or list item. Nothing from tagging